# Soap Message input/output element count

Tags: soap, wsdl

I have been working on the soap message parsing, is there a any possibility that there can be more than one input and output for an operation in a wsdl file

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about input and output parameters then yes it can be more than one input and output. For e.g.:

```
<xsd:element name="yourMethod">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="param1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xsd:element name="param2" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="param3" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="yourMethodResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="results" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

You can pass as many parameters as you want. If you want to return a list of values you have to specify this: `maxOccurs="unbounded"`. This will tell your stack to generate method with the return type which is in this case list of `String` values.

Be aware that this is just `XSD` elements, you will need to declare them as `WSDL` operations.